# How to Hide MKAnnotationView Callout?

Tags: iphone, sdk, mkannotation, mkannotationview, callouts

i'm trying to hide an AnnotationView without touching the pin, is the possible?
Thanks!

```
for (id currentAnnotation in self.mapView.annotations) {        
if ([currentAnnotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]]) { 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Do you just want to make the callout bubble go away but keep the pin?
If yes, then do this:

```
for (id currentAnnotation in self.mapView.annotations) {        
    if ([currentAnnotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]]) { 
        [self.mapView deselectAnnotation:currentAnnotation animated:YES];
    } 
}
```